# Cloud architecture pattern for multiple simple api clients (200-500m api calls/day)?

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, amazon-web-services, design-patterns

I have to write an api-client system that connects to multiple api-servers, does a job and disconnects. It does two simple things, but needs to do it at scale (ie: aiming for 200-500m outbound API client calls per day):

(1) Simple client connects to an API-server (http/rest), sends a query, receives a response (text based), saves the response for later, and moves on to the next server/query.

Once responses start coming in, a separate process will:

(2) parse the text in the responses and add them to a large file/queue for reporting

I currently have a test system in C#, running 20 console applications on a machine, with 20 threaded clients in each console application carrying out the work. I need to be able to scale this up on demand. What is the best approach to do this? ... I am sure a solid pattern exists to this simple problem?

My thoughts so far are:

-> design a management system that depending on the volume of API-servers to be queried in a given hour, orchestrates the provisioning of virtual machines (not trying to redesign the wheel - will hook into any existing framework like chef/puppet etc if suitable)

-> have a central system for collection of data from the api-clients (perhaps a node instance passing the data off to RabbitMQ for later pickup/processing)

-> have a separate management system that orchestrates the text parsing of data received from the API clients.

-> As project is network latency bound, I believe development language is not really relevant so long as it has good network support.

My main questions then are around:

(1) What would be a most appropriate language/framework to implement this in to enable a lean/cost-effective system? ... ie: no point in spinning up multiple Windows VMs for example if they have a bigger footprint/overhead/cost than doing the same thing in linux? (so in this case I could use the mono framework - get the benefit of C# that my team knows, but the lower cost of linux VMs...)

(2) Is my thinking about having to spin multiple VMs up to do this correct (albeit small VMs running X client applications each)?

(3) Another approach I thought of is to write the clients in Javascript - the reason being that the bottleneck for the api-client is network and api-server response time, not client-side, so it might be well suited to async work? .... in this case I could have one Node server running 100x more api-clients than I could ever get in even a bunch of micro-windows VMs ?

(4) Finally, am I reinventing the wheel? ... is there anything out there on Amazon or Azure already that I can plug into that would provide a ready framework for what I need?

All comments and suggestions and guidance most welcome.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a specialist in what Amazon provides. Here is what you can use on Azure depending on your needs:

1. **Worker role** - this is pretty much a scalable virtual machine. You can scale out or autoscale by condition.
2. **AppFabric and Microservices** - for more complex deployment and more granulated development infrastructures.
3. **Azure Functions** - an interesting scalable and cost effective processing option. Check it out.

In terms of choosing the language, I would use Node.js if your application is not too complex and it's not going to in the near future. C# is better for more solid systems with complex architecture. Both platforms are supported on Azure.

> Have a central system for collection of data from the api-clients
>   (perhaps a node instance passing the data off to RabbitMQ for later
>   pickup/processing)

If you need a really big throughput, RabbitMQ may not be enough. On Azure you can use **EventHub**. More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/).

Comment: Many thanks Andrei - will see what others add.

Answer (score 1):

"Finally, am I reinventing the wheel?" Its a good question - you might be.  From your description, you have a lot of proprietary management of servers going on - and a lot of VMs. Depending on your workload, you may not need need manage *any* traditional VMs at all.  Avoid that if you can to keep things lean.  There are some great technologies that make server management (patching, security, server administration, etc) a thing of the past for many work loads: event-driven computing frameworks such as AWS Lambda.

Consider a server-less implementation using the [API gateway pattern](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/), and [microservice architecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) pattern, using the following AWS services:

1. [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) is a compute service where you can upload your code to AWS Lambda and the service can run the code on your behalf using AWS infrastructure. After you upload your code and create what we call a Lambda function, AWS Lambda takes care of **provisioning and managing the servers** that you use to run the code. Very light weight. The first 1 million requests per month are free
2. "[Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/) is a fully managed service that makes it easy for developers to publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs at any scale." $3.50 per million calls. Scaling, security and management all built in.  Lambda supports the specification of HTTP endpoints via the API Gateway to trigger Lambda functions.

> AWS Lambda provides an easy way to build back ends without managing
>   servers. API Gateway and Lambda together can be powerful to create and
>   deploy serverless Web applications. In this walkthrough, you learn how
>   to create Lambda functions and build an API Gateway API to enable a
>   Web client to call the Lambda functions synchronously.

You can also integrate [DataPipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) for data transformation, and [Simple Queueing Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) for queuing/messaging, if needed you your workloads.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo - I think the API gateway is more geared towards APIs that are designed to 'listen' (as api servers) - in my case, I have multiple clients that are designed to 'talk to' remote apis (as api clients) ... so in this case they dont have to maintain large numbers of client connections. AWS Lambda is interesting however - seems to be similar to Azure Functions.

Comment: The API Gateway is a service that clients call at any scale. It is the API endpoint of your app. Your clients would call to the API Gateway..  That is what it does: "Gateway handles all the tasks involved in accepting and processing up to hundreds of thousands of concurrent API calls, including traffic management, authorization and access control, monitoring, and API version management."

Comment: indeed, I didnt explain perhaps - I am in this case, having a large volume of api *clients* calling *other/external* API servers ... this app itself, is not the API.

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing anything stateful and at scale Service Fabric might be the better choice over Azure Functions/Lambda or Worker Roles.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/

Comment: thanks - I will add it to the list of things to check out!